# How is it possible that jax vmap returns not iterable?

Tags: python, jax

```
import jax
import pgx
from jax import vmap, jit
import jax.numpy as jnp

env = pgx.make("tic_tac_toe")
key = jax.random.PRNGKey(42)

states = jax.jit(vmap(env.init))(jax.random.split(key, 4))
type(states)
```

`states` has a type `pgx.tic_tac_toe.State`. I was expecting an Iterable object with a size 4. Somehow iterable results are inside `pgx.tic_tac_toe.State`.

Can you please explain how is it possible that jax vmap returns not iterable?

How to force vmap to return the next result:

```
states = [env.init(key) for key in jax.random.split(key, 4)]
```

Note, this code works as expected:

```
def square(x):
    return x ** 2
inputs = jnp.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
result = jax.vmap(square)(inputs)
print(result) # list object
```

Comment: A quick glance at the documentation makes me thing you want `vmap(env.init, jax.random.split(key, 4))`.  I don't really know Jax, though.

Comment: I have updated the code with working example: jax.vmap(square)(inputs). Your suggestion seems incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please explain how is it possible that jax vmap returns not iterable?

When passed a non-array object, `vmap` will map the leading axes of each array in its flattened [pytree](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pytrees.html) representation. You can see the shapes in the flattened object here:

```py
print([arr.shape for arr in jax.tree_util.tree_flatten(states)[0]])
# [(4,), (4, 3, 3, 2), (4, 2), (4,), (4,), (4, 9), (4,), (4,), (4, 9)]
```

This is an example of the *struct-of-arrays* pattern used by `vmap`, where it sounds like you were expececting an *array-of-structs* pattern.

> How to force vmap to return the next result

If you wanted to convert this output into the list of state objects you were expecting, you could do so using utilities in `jax.tree_util`:

```py
leaves, treedef = jax.tree_util.tree_flatten(states)
states_list = [treedef.unflatten(leaf) for leaf in zip(*leaves)]
print(len(states_list))
# 4
```

That said, it appears that `pgx` is built to work natively with the original struct-of-arrays pattern, so you may find that you won't actually need this unstacked version in practice.